# Solving equations with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to solve:
$Z^3+\bar{\omega^7} = 0$ and $Z^5\omega^{11}=1$
From the second equation, I got $Z^5=\omega$ and from the first I got $Z^3=-\omega^2$. I plugged in omega from the first result into $Z^3=-\omega^2$, giving me $Z=0$ or $Z^7=-1$, finally giving me 8 solutions:$0,-1,-\alpha...-\alpha^6$.

This is incorrect. Why? 
Also, what is the correct way to solve complex equations?

Comment: Is $\omega$ complex cube root of unity?

Comment: yes, it is the cube root of unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $\omega$ is a root of unity, but not necessarily a *cube* root of unity, and see what happens.

It's clear that $Z\not=0$.  The equation $Z^3+\overline\omega^7=0$ can be rewritten as $Z^3\omega^7=-1$, which, by squaring both sides, implies $Z^6\omega^{14}=1$.  Combining with the other equation, $Z^5\omega^{11}=1$, gives $Z\omega^3=1$, or $Z=\overline\omega^3$.

Plugging $Z=\overline\omega^3$ into $Z^3\omega^7=-1$, we find $\overline\omega^2=-1$, which means $\omega=\pm i$, and this implies $Z=\pm(-i)^3=\pm i$.

In other words, what we've shown is that in order for the simultaneous equations $Z^3+\overline\omega^7=0$ and $Z^5\omega^{11}=1$ to have a solution with $\omega$ a root of unity, we must have $Z=\omega=\pm i$.

Comment: Z=-i does not satisfy the equation

Comment: @xasthor, it does if $\omega=-i$.  If $Z=i$ is supposed to be the only solution, then there is something about the problem that's been left out.  In any event, your comment confirming that $\omega$ is a cube root of unity cannot be correct.

Comment: Why didn't you squaring both sides of the equation $Z^3\omega^7=-1$ introduce an extraneous root

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$$z^3=-\overline{\omega}^7\\z^5=\frac{1}{\omega^{11}}$$ note that $$(z^5)^3=(z^3)^5$$so 
$$(z^5)^3=(z^3)^5\\
(\frac{1}{\omega^{11}})^3=(-\overline{\omega}^7)^5\\
\frac{1}{\omega^33}=-\overline{\omega}^{35}\\-\overline{\omega}^{35}\times \omega^33=1\\\to 
-(\omega \overline{\omega})^{33}.\overline{\omega}^{2}=1\\-(|\omega|^2)^{33}.\overline{\omega}^{2}=1$$ in the other hand 
$$z^5\omega^{11}=1 \to z^6\omega^{11}=z \\ (-\overline{\omega}^7)^2\omega^{11}=z\\\overline{\omega}^{11}\overline{\omega}^3\omega^{11}=z \\\overline{\omega}^3=z$$

Comment: What is wrong with what I did? The correct answer is z= i

Comment: Show your work here please ,there are math.man here to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I did show my work in the question

Comment: From where YOU GOT $Z^5=\omega $ ?

Comment: $Z^5(w)^{11} =z^5 (w)^9.w^2 = z^5w^2 =1$ which gives $Z^5=w$

Comment: If you plug $i$ in for $Z$ it does not work.  The solution is not $Z=i$,